# Trouble adding image from url into list view

Tags: android, xml, image, parsing, listview

I am Building an app which shows some images and information into a listview .
Here is my main activity,

```
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://starkgot.host56.com/first.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
static final String KEY_DIRECTOR = "director";
static final String KEY_CAST = "cast";
static final String KEY_video = "video";
static final String KEY_image = "image";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
ImageView imageview12=(ImageView)findviewbyid(R.id.item_icon);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE));
        map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION));
        map.put(KEY_DIRECTOR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DIRECTOR));
        map.put(KEY_CAST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CAST));
        map.put(KEY_video, parser.getValue(e, KEY_video));
        map.put(KEY_image, parser.getValue(e, KEY_image));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }
Picasso.with(this).load(KEY_image).into(imageview12)   

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE,
                    KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_DIRECTOR, KEY_CAST, KEY_video,KEY_image}, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.date,
                    R.id.description, R.id.director, R.id.cast, R.id.video,R.id.image});//image not getting loaded here!!!

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();
            String director = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.director))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cast = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cast))
                    .getText().toString();
            String video = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.video))
                    .getText().toString();
            String image = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.image))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, date);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DIRECTOR, director);
            in.putExtra(KEY_CAST, cast);
            in.putExtra(KEY_video, video);
            in.putExtra(KEY_image, image);

            startActivity(in);

        }

    });

}
}
```

The XML Parsing is done properly and the second class for activity displayed after each item on list is clicked is also done properly .
How can i add a image factor just like the other factors like name description etc in my listview.

Comment: As i understood, you want to pass an image as you pass name to the next activity, am i right? If im wright, then you need to pass the URL Path to the image just like you put all other extras on the intent, and then, on the other activity, when receive the image URL, you asignt it to the list, this is done commonly using an Adapter for the listview, which handles all content for the list. check this Tutorial from Vogella "http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html", which explains a lot about listviews and how to use them.

Comment: No that is not what i want,i want to display the image on the listview on this activity itself.

Comment: Well, in your activity, store the information you want to show, maybe an ArrayList with the URL's, or something like that, and then, use it as an adapter to fill your list.

Comment: As u can see in the above code i have used list adapter to add specific values into respective textview's now i want a way to add image from url in that same list....i have done some changes in the code ...when i add the picasso thing there are no errors but the app does not run

Comment: Well, You should use a Lazy Loading for your image, check this out: http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134, because if you set your image directly, as you do with your text, your app will lag while it's loading images and you will see the ANR message.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use any Image loading Library.

I suggest to use "Universal Image Loader", check [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

If you found problem in implementing it use [this](http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android) to learn how to use it.